# objective - c lowercaseString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, nsstringencoding

special characters in lowercase letters in a word, failing.
sample:

```
NSLog(@"%@",name);
name = [name lowercaseString];
NSLog(@"%@",name);

2013-06-24 23:32:11.590  Player[12739:907]   BİLİYORSUN..
2013-06-24 23:32:11.590  Player[12739:907]   bi̇li̇yorsun..

2013-06-24 23:36:09.504  Player[12739:907]  İTÜ
2013-06-24 23:36:09.505  Player[12739:907]  i̇tü
```

"i" "İ" seem distorted letters. What should I do?
thanks.

the output is supposed to be this way: the right thing

```
2013-06-24 23:36:09.505  Player[12739:907]  itü 
2013-06-24 23:32:11.590  Player[12739:907]  biliyorsun..
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue is.  Capital and Lowercase are both I with Grave.  [Reference](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reference the UTF-8 char table found [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).  This seems to be normal behavior, as your capital and lowercase 'İ' both are of the type 'I with Grave'.

Comment: 2013-06-24 23:32:11.590  Player[12739:907]   biliyorsun..   2013-06-24 23:36:09.505  Player[12739:907]  itü                     the output is supposed to be this way

Comment: I don't see a difference between the output you are looking for and the output you posted.

Comment: There are two points on the letter i. required to have one point.

Answer (score 0):

Use this .

```
NSString *str=@"TESTING";
str = [str lowercaseString];
 NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

and output is : testing

Please use this type of code.thanks